# REGEX: Match everything except partial match

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match everything except a given string (partial match) : https://play.google.com/variable

I managed to do exactly the opposite at the moment by using the following regex:

```
(\S*play\.google\.com\S*)
```

which does select the only string I actually want to keep, so I want my regex to select all the text EXCEPT the one above (basically the opposite of what I just did).

I tried negative lookahead but it didn't work, hope you can help me. Full code available here: https://regexr.com/3h4se

If possible, I'd also love a jsfiddle which will strip away everything except that url, using your modified regex, so that the final output will just be:

```
https://play.google.com/variable
```

Good luck!

Comment: You cannot use a pure regex here. Actually, it is better done without a regex. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yn4wfo0c/2/). `s.split(/\s+/).filter(function(x) { return x.indexOf('play.google.com') > -1;})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this, using a negative lookahead:

`^(?!https:\/\/play\.google\.com\/variable).*`

**Live example:**

https://regexr.com/3h4sq

Note that we can still successfully match substrings of the URL like "google" and "variable" while still excluding the full URL match.

**Edit:**

Here's another way to do it without the lookahead, using [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) from Rexegg.com:

```
https:\/\/play\.google\.com\/variable|(.*)
```

And return group 1:

```
$1
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to make a live example using jquery replace in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @LucaSbenaglia sorry, I'm not a JS developer, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Can you do it without Global and without Multiline?

Comment: I don't need to select the rest of the line, your code matches also any words after my string.

Comment: @LucaSbenaglia I'd look at what Wiktor suggested in the comments, that's probably a better solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear what you're trying to do; but this is what I came up with:

^([\s\S]*)?(\S*)(https://play.google.com/\S*)([\s\S]*)\g

then replace: $1$2$4

Comment: I'd like to get that specific link of a given text, and then to use it in jQuery.load to get a thumbnail picture in that page to display it on my site.

Answer (score 0):

I would capture everything before and after into groups. Like this:

```
/([^]*)play\.google\.com([^]*)/
```

That way all you need is to replace the original text with the group before and after. e. g.:

```
original_text.replace(/([^]*)play\.google\.com([^]*)/, '$1$2');
```

This will give you all text before joined with all text after.

P.S. This will only work if there is 1 and only 1 phrase "play.google.com" in the text.